# Double blocking in deck - how to install straight-line double blocking?

Tags: framing, deck, railing, blocking

In preparing to build a guardrail with posts on the outside of the deck, I see a diagram in the Simpson PDF (bottom left diagram on page 3 of https://ssttoolbox.widen.net/view/pdf/xeuwdrqaen/T-C-GRDRLPST22.pdf?t.download=true&u=cjmyin) which shows two sets of straight line double blocking.

How is this supposed to be attached to the joists?  Through toe nailing one side of the blocking, toe nailing both sides, hangers / connectors for the blocking, or some other method?  I want to make sure this is very strong and not improperly done.

Answer (score 1):

Talking with a GC there are two recommended options - the first being more expensive but easier (unless experienced at toe nailing):

1. Install joist hangers first on both sides of the gap and then lower the blocking into it and fasten from the faces which are accessible
2. End nail one side, then toe nail the other side.  This is done by toe nailing both faces of the block which is installed first and then just toe nailing the accessible face of the second block since it's impossible to do both faces, and both blocks will be pressed against each other for interior support. Repeat this for the next set.  [In theory you could end nail both ends of the first set of blocking but not the next set]

Comment: So when it tells you to use 13x3" nails on each block, where are the 13 nails located?  I assume the most common install is going to be 2 since this is just blocking and generally framers aren't wasting hangers on blocking.

Comment: If this is in reference to attaching the tension ties, they come with 1-1/2" fasteners.

Comment: your link page 3/4 - "Detail B: Fasten each blocking together with (13) 0.148" x 3" nails".  I don't think this is in reference to the tension ties as you point out those are fastened with 1.5" screws.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - I was originally just wondering how to attach the blocking to the joists, but good callout with regards to connecting the two to each other as that's very relevant.